# user perl's rename in Windows cmd.exe, like in linux/bash?

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, rename

Is there no way to use perl's rename directly from the cli in windows as can be done in bash on gnu/linux?
Like

```
rename 's/\ /_/g' *
```

I have a script to do some renaming (namefix.pl

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 print join("\n",map{$o=$_;y/A-Z ,()[]/a-z_-/;s/_-_/-/g;s/-\././g;rename($o,$_)?$_:"Didn't rename $o: $!"}<*>),"\n";
```

) that does the spaces and other stuff just great, but I mean, on the fly renaming stuff straight from the cli without calling a script, using the above simply as an example of how I would do it in a bash terminal (as if you folks didn't already know).

If not, is there any simple means of using regexp in renaming stuff in the windows cmd.exe?
(afaik, windows' ren  doesn't do regexp, but maybe it does...this whole crappy OS is basically new to me after using only gnu/linux for the past 14 years, and I'm not thrilled about having to work with it now...ugh). Any viable alternative would be as acceptable to me as the perl. I just want to get stuff done. I'm not picky.

Comment: Perl has a builtin `rename` function but that doesn't do anything fancy with regular expressions. You are talking about a GNU/Linux tool called `rename`?

Comment: Yes, but on debian, at least, as far as I understand, the rename tool IS perl's rename. This is what I'm talking about. There used to be another, but it was replaced with perl's rename, and the old one moved to rename.ul (whereas for a while, the perl rename was still rename.pl).

Comment: I'm not sure we should be confusing [perl's `rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) with a perl script named "rename".

Comment: It's not "Perl's `rename`". It's a script written in Perl named `rename`. It does not come with Perl. It should work perfectly fine on Windows except you might have to use `/` instead of `\ ` as the dir sep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If calling a perl script for your renaming needs is good enough for you on Linux, they why not do it on Windows too?  Both ActiveState & Strawberry will modify your registry to associate .pl files with their implementation of perl.

Copy the script to Windows, add a .pl extension & make sure it's in your PATH.

If you'd like to call it without typing in the '.pl' then you can even tell windows that .pl is an 'executable extension' with the PATHEXT environment variable.  Of course if you do this then you should heed the warning below & use a name that doesn't conflict with the OS built-ins. (Good catch, Ikegami)

Comment: One catch: It would have to be named something other than `rename` as that would conflict with the builtin also known as `ren`.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that with one script, namefix.pl, I mentioned above. I have the strawberry perl installed.

Comment: I found the script that comes in Debian (at least a version of it from 2007), and have placed it in my path on the Winbox as prename.pl (actually the name of the script; in Debian, rename is provided by prename, which is prename.pl).